# Force close file on NFS opened by someone else

Tags: nfs

Any way this can be done on Linux or Windows where you don't have to be an admin? Maybe if you're the owner of the file you should be able to force it to close if it's opened by someone else?

Edit:
I am not looking for a way to do it on both, the best way to do it overall is what I'm shooting for.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I believe there is no way to force a client to close the file. NFS v2 and v3 even do not have operations like OPEN and CLOSE. With v4.1 server may recall file layout from a client, but there are no administrative command to trigger that. IOW, you can't do it.